# Unable to install Conexant USB modem type 0572:1340 in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, software-installation, usb-modem

I am new to Linux. I 've tried to install drivers for my Conexant FU07 USB modem but neither the Linuxant drivers nor the installer CD ones (dgcmodem_1.13_i386.deb) get properly installed.

The scanModem tool did not find much about the modem.

The `lsusb` output is:

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0572:1340 Conexant Systems (Rockwell), Inc.
```

The `dpkg --list | grep --ignore-case dgc` output is:

```
ii  dgcmodem:i386   1.13   i386   Conexant DGC USB modem driver
```

And relevant part of the `dmesg` output is:

```
[19432.393516] usb 2-1.3: new full-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[19432.522961] usb 2-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=0572, idProduct=1340
[19432.522968] usb 2-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[19432.522972] usb 2-1.3: Product: USB Modem
[19432.522975] usb 2-1.3: Manufacturer: Conexant
[19432.522978] usb 2-1.3: SerialNumber: 12345678
[19432.544244] cdc_acm 2-1.3:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
```

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  What's the output to `dpkg --list | grep --ignore-case dgc`? Please [edit] your question to provide this relevant infor there...

Comment: It looks like the modem driver is installed correctly. Test it it `minicom`. The device is `/dev/ttyACM0`.

Comment: Minicom states: `Port /dev/tty8`.  What do i do next?

Comment: @Pilot6  The modem is installed...  OP's Q is answered.  Shall you answer or I?

Comment: @Fabby Answer please.

Comment: @AZ You can use the modem now. You can send commands there and connect somewhere,

Comment: `sudo minicom --device=/dev/ttyACM0`

Comment: What software are you using. You need to tell it that the modem is `/dev/ttyACM0`.

Comment: @Pilot6 Done!  :-) :-) :-)

Comment: Thank you very much, favor returned, question upvoted!  **;-)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your modem is now installed correctly as per:

`dpkg --list | grep --ignore-case dgc` output:

```
ii  dgcmodem:i386   1.13   i386   Conexant DGC USB modem driver
```

And relevant part of the dmesg output:

```
[19432.544244] cdc_acm 2-1.3:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
```

Have fun [exploring modem and serial commands](https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Modem-HOWTO-4.html)

Comment: How can I set it up to send and receive fax using a gui like Efax-gtk?

Comment: In Efax-gtk I get the following error:    efax-0.9a: 13:14:16 Error: can't open serial port /dev/ttyACM0: Permission denied.   Also in LibreOffice Writer's Print menu I don't get a Fax option. Only "my printer" and the "print to file" options.   I appreciate your help and thank you for letting me know that the driver is installed. It seems that I need to do some more setting up. Could you please advise me how to proceed? Thanks

Comment: I 've been doing some reading on modem and serial port commands. Using the `ls -l /dev/tty` command I found that I don't have permission to that port (8 out of 9 ports are listed under root). Could somebody guide me to change the permission for that port? tty8 (or ttyACM0) is the port i need permission to.

Comment: Your original question has now been answered.  Please don't forget to accept the answer by clicking the grey acceptance button turning it into a beautiful green.  **:-)** Then [ask a new question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) and refer with a link to this question if you would have a different question that relates to this one as this is not a forum but a Q&A site: one question, one answer.  **;-)**